# How can I convert/store multiple ENUM selections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I am able to convert an `enum` to a `string` with the following code. However, it only stores ONE of the selected values. In the case where TWO values are selected, it is truncated when I store it using NHibernate.

Here is my code:

```
MyEnum { One, Two, Three, Four, Five }

private static readonly string[] myEnum =
    Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));
public string MyProperty
{
    get {
        var value = new MyEnum();
        int i = (int)value;
        return i >= 0 && i < myEnum.Length ?
            myEnum[i] : i.ToString(); }
    set { 
        Record.MyProperty= value == 
            null ? null : String.Join(",", value); }
}
```

`Record` is just `public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }`

Can anyone provide a sample of how I would store, for example in comma-separated form, multiple `enum`'s that are selected (e.g., "One, Two, Five" are selected by the user and all three are stored in the DB)?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to do this in the `get{}`:

```
foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
{
    return i >= 0 && i < myEnum.Length ? myEnum[i] : i.ToString();
}
```

but am getting a `not all code paths return a value` error.

**QUESTION UPDATE:**

If I did this with two `string`'s:

```
part.MyProperty = record.MyProperty;
```

Using `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` answer below from @Jamie Ide won't work because I cannot convert `string` to `MyEnum`.

How would I write that last part to get the `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` code from @Jamie Ide in the answer below to work?

Comment: @frictionlesspulley Would you be able to roll up an example in an Answer that I can then check off if it works? Thanks!

Comment: The MyProperty you show accepts a single string in it's setter and does string.Join on that, which looks "unexpected". Everything you have takes and returns string - why are you not exposing the MyEnum more? And why myEnum? It contains the same values as someEnum.ToString() will give you. Why not store it as a ISet<MyEnum>?

Comment: The reason for the `not all code paths return a value` error is because nothing will be returned if there are no values in your Enum (i.e. the loop never runs).  You could just add a dummy `return ""` at the end to make the compiler happy.

Comment: Is it a requirement to store as a string? Have you considered storing as an `int` or `long` and adding the `[Flags]` attribute to the enum, then doing bitwise comparisons to get the list of enums?

Comment: @Josh I tried something along those lines but was unable to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, unless it's an absolute requirement to store the enum as a string I'd recommend setting your enum up with the `[Flags]` attribute and creating a convention to store the enum as an int. Here's what I use (note I'm using FluentNH):

**The convention**

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        // You can use this if you don't want to support nullable enums
        // criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum);

        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum ||
            (x.Property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) &&
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsEnum)
            );
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance target)
    {
        target.CustomType(target.Property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

**The enum**
Note you have to be careful what you set the values to in order to keep the bitwise comparison working.

```
// Note I use long to support enough enum values
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum : long
{
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 1 << 1,
    Baz = 1 << 2
}
```

You shouldn't have to do anything beyond that, I believe. No need to iterate to set or retrieve, nothing. To test for the presence of a value, you can use the `HasFlag()` extension method on the enum.

### Update

To modify the MvcGrabBag code to support this kind of enum, you'll need to change the `GetItemsFromEnum` method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum<T>(T enumeration = default(T)) where T : struct
{
    FieldInfo[] fields = enumeration.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    return from field in fields
                let value = Enum.Parse(enumeration.GetType(), field.Name)
                let descriptionAttributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = descriptionAttributes.Length > 0
                                ? ((DescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0]).Description
                                : field.Name,
                    Value = Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString(),
                    Selected = (Convert.ToInt64(enumeration) & Convert.ToInt64(value)) == Convert.ToInt64(value)
                };
}
```

Note that I kept it as a generic only because I don't know what other aspects of that toolkit depend on that signature. You can see that it's not necessary, though -- you can remove the `<T>` and have the signature like `public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum(Enum enumeration)` and it'll work fine.

Note also that this code is using my convention of supporting names derived from the `Description` attribute. I use this to let my labels be more human-readable. The enum would look like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum : long
{
    [Description("Super duper foo")]
    Foo = 1,
    [Description("Super duper bar")]
    Bar = 1 << 1,
    // With no description attribute it will use the ToString value
    Baz = 1 << 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem I mentioned I was having was in my use of a custom "Selector" attribute on the property (i.e., `[MySelector]`). Because I use this to auto select check box, radio button, drop down, etc. when using `enum`'s, I am getting a `The Field ... must be a number` as an error on validating the page. I assume this is because the "Selector" I use puts the `enum` in a `SelectList`. The code is long and I don't wanna waste your time, but if you wanna see it lemme know.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to see it. I have similar requirements to show selections in a checkbox list, so if I can figure out how to make your custom selector work with flags it'll save me a few foreach loops.

Comment: Well, that's good to hear. Rather than post here is a link to CodePlex where I got it from: [MvcGrabBag on CodePlex](http://mvcgrabbag.codeplex.com/). It's under the "/Selectors" folder (`Selector.cs`). There is also a template under the "/Shared/EditorTemplates" folder (`Selector.cshtml`) - this one contains the logic to display the appropriate input. Hopefully it's useful to you.

Comment: You're going to have to modify the `Selector` class so that the value assigned in the `GetItemsFromEnum` method isn't the string value of the enum, it's the int value. You'll have to modify that entire block so that the conversion to string happens in the loop.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines when I first encountered this problem, except 1) I am not a programmer by trade, and 2) I am using 20 or so other `enum`'s which are not affected by this (it's only multi-select inputs like checkboxes and multi-lists). So figuring out how to switch between checkboxes and the other inputs is beyond me. Thanks for trying.

Comment: That last sentence in your last comment "You'll have to modify that entire block so that the conversion to string happens in the loop" - were you referring to the loop in the `.cshtml` Editor Template? Or did you mean to say the conversion to `int` happens in the loop?

Comment: I meant in the `Selector` class. There's a method called `GetItemsFromEnum` that uses a linq `select` to create the `SelectList`. You can see that it pulls the string value of the enum, sets the text using a call to `.Wordify()` (which I assume adds spaces to a camel case name), then sets the value to the string value of the enum. If you modified that so that you used the int value of the enum and *then* converted to a string for the text value, you'd end up with the correct setup that would let the modelbinder recognize a Flags enum.

Comment: woops, how did you define `enumeration`?

Comment: Updated again with the full method. You can probably try to make it not generic and see if it still works.

Comment: @Josh Two questions: 1) Do you place the `EnumConvention` code in a separate project and reference, or in the same project and reference somehow in the code? 2) I cannot get this to save more than one selection, e.g., if I select what is `1` and `2` as `[Flags]` (which should save as `3`, right?), I only get `1` in the database. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the convention is the issue. You're getting back a collection of individual values when you post the form, which means your controller is going to have to expect a collection and merge them by setting a single enum variable using something along the lines of `MyEnum selections = value1 | value2 | value3`. Not sure if you're using a ViewModel, but if so you might want to store values as `List<MyEnum>` and merge them for persisting via NH.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty solution. In this solution, _myEnumString would be mapped as a private field and stored in the database. As mentioned in the comments, it is possible to store the array as a collection using another table as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606607/mapping-collection-of-strings-with-nhibernate) or in one table as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768788/what-nhibernate-mapping-is-used-for-string-in-an-entity).

```
    public enum MyEnum { One, Two, Three, Four, Five }

public class MyClass
{
    private string _myEnumString;

    public IEnumerable<MyEnum> MyEnums
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Array.ConvertAll(_myEnumString.Split(','), s => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s));
        }
        set
        {
            _myEnumString = string.Join(",", value.Select(v => v.ToString()));
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE

Assuming record.MyProperty and part.MyProperty are both delimited strings of MyEnum names (e.g. "One,Two,Three") then you can map MyProperty and create a read only property to return the collection of MyEnum.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MyEnum> MyEnums
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Array.ConvertAll(MyProperty.Split(','), s => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks viable, but now when I try to save the record in the DB, I get an error with the existing code I use. Please see the "Question Update" in my post above. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that update's not working. If I do `part.MyProperty = record.MyProperty;` to save in the DB, I am getting a cast error (`string` to `IEnumerable`). Doing your update does nothing to fix that. How would I write `part.MyProperty = [What goes here]`

Comment: So this isn't true? "Assuming record.MyProperty and part.MyProperty are both delimited strings of MyEnum names..." I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: First part of my question is what I am trying to do. If I make both of those strings I can save ONE of the enums, but when I try the `foreach` loop to try and store MORE than just ONE, I get the error I specified. When I tried the code you first suggested I got the cast error (`string` to `IEnumerable`).